# Compute bulk electrical conducitivity from single-crystal measurements

Tags: electronic-structure, crystallography, physical-properties-of-materials, experimental

If I have single-crystal measurements of electrical conductivity along 3D axes (considering for example anisotropic materials), is there any straightforward way to compute the bulk (global) electrical conductivity, to have a *compact* measurement?

Comment: I am not sure if "BoltzTraP" code might help.

Comment: This question needs clarification. There is no such thing of a "global" electrical conductivity of a single-crystal with anisotropic conductivity. Are you asking about the conductivity of a polycrystalline sample?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or someone would like to provide an answer.